# How do I make a basic Paypal Express Checkout call using the PHP SDK?

Tags: php, paypal

The only documentation on how to use Paypal's Merchant SDK for PHP I've been able to find covers how to install it using Composer and that's it. No explanation for how to initialize the SDK or make a SetExpressCheckout call.

How do I initialize the SDK and make a SetExpressCheckout call using it?

Update:
This question was closed, but if anyone comes upon it, I found an example of how to initialize it in the merchant-sdk-php downloads:

```
merchant-sdk-php/samples/SimpleSamples/SetExpressCheckout.php 
merchant-sdk-php/samples/SimpleSamples/SetExpressCheckout.html.php
```

Comment: [Any of these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=express+checkout+php) any good?

Comment: I think the SDK was only for the REST api.

Comment: The only way I can think of getting an answer to this (bearing in mind that it is likely off-topic) is to list in your question (by editing it) the most likely links in the Paypal devs site that ought to contain this information, but don't. The only way people can help here, I think, is for searching for the information themselves, so if you show that you've already done that thoroughly, devs au fait with this stuff may be able to point you the right way.

Comment: I would recommend you use [my class library](http://www.angelleye.com/download-angell-eye-php-class-library-for-paypal/) instead.  It's got better documentation and is much easier to get going with.